# $\int_{0}^x f_j(t) dt$ converges uniformly to $\int_{0}^x f_0(t) dt$ if $f_j \to f_0$ in $L^2$ sense.

Tags: functional-analysis, proof-verification

> Suppose $\{f_j\}$ converges to $f_0$ in $L^2$ sense. Show that the functions $F_j (x) = \int_{0}^x f_j(t) dt$ converges uniformly to $\int_{0}^x f_0(t) dt$ for all $x \in [-\pi,\pi]$.

My proof: 
Let $\epsilon > 0$. We want to find $N$ such that whenever $j>N$,
\begin{equation}
    \bigl| \int_{0}^x f_j (t) dt - \int_{0}^x f_0 (t) dt \bigr| < \epsilon \text{ for all } x \in [-\pi,\pi]
\end{equation}
Apply Cauchy Schwarz,

$$\bigl| \int_{0}^x f_j (t) dt - \int_{0}^x f_0 (t) dt \bigr|  \le \int_{0}^x |f_j (t) - f_0 (t) | dt\\
 \le \left(\int_{0}^x (f_j(t) - f_0(t))^2 dt\right)^\frac{1}{2} \left( \int_{0}^x 1 dt\right)^\frac{1}{2}\\
\le \left(\int_{-\pi}^\pi (f_j(t) - f_0(t))^2 dt\right)^\frac{1}{2} \left(\int_{-\pi}^\pi 1 df\right)^\frac{1}{2}\\
= \|f_j - f_0\|_{L^2} \sqrt{2\pi}$$
Since $f_j$ converges to $f_0$ in $L^2$ sense, the result follows.

I want to make sure I did this proof correctly. Thanks.

Comment: Seems correct for me...